# Laravel: Sharing same framework across multiple applications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am planning to have two sub domains to deploy two instances of the same laravel 
application. Those will be DEV and TEST. Can it be installed like this or do I have to have separate installation for each instance?

I think if I can share the framework files, when upgrading, it will be easier than upgrading two. Please do share your knowledge if this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I get this entirely but you are trying to deploy the same project twice (dev & test servers). If that's the case, then it's very easy. It's just one project on two different domain names. You have a couple of options:

1. Put the project on your server and make both domains point to the same folder. So `dev.com` and `test.com` both point to `.../www/project/public`.
2. 2 different instances on 2 different servers. Still easy. Place your project on bitbucket or github. Go to both server and git pull. When upgrading, you will only upgrade once, on local server, then go to both servers and just git pull again.

Database-wise, you can give them 2 difference databases instances as well. Just do it in the `.env` and they will each point to their respective database. Still, you only upgrade once, and git pull.

Comment: TEST is not a clone of DEV, so that solution 1 is not applicable. It seemed to me that the second solution is OK as far as I can see. As I understood, this solution still maintains two separate code bases (for framework) and you have described a way to get rid of upgrading process of doing twice both DEV and TEST. Instead, upgrade local server and do a git pull to both DEV and TEST which will essentially upgrade DEV and TEST. :) Did I get your idea correctly?